# How to convert object to JSON of an integer field having leading zeros using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I try to convert an object having an integer field with value as `0000`,
the converted JSON contains `0` instead of `0000`.

How can I configure Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to convert `0000` to `00000`?

Comment: 0000 is not a decimal integer. I don't think that's possible at all, though you could store it as a String

Comment: You can’t do that because `0000` is not valid in JSON. See http://www.json.org/ for the format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leading 0 indicates an octal number. Hence leading zeros are not allowed for numeric values in JSON. See the following quote from the [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

> [**6.  Numbers**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6)
>
> The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most
> programming languages.  **A number is represented in base 10 using
> decimal digits.**  It contains an integer component that may be
> prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by a
> fraction part and/or an exponent part.  **Leading zeros are not
> allowed.**

If you need leading zeros, consider using a string.