# How to bind Integer with leading zeros to an Integer field in request payload in Spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jax-rs

I have a payload like following.

```
{
    "name": "XXXX",
    "expMonth": 07,
    "expYear": 21
}
```

My Request Body POJO is something like below.

```
public Class Card {
     private String name;
     private Integer expMonth;
     private Integer expYear;
}
```

However, `expMonth` is not binding properly and throws an exception. Please suggest the way forward.

**Exception Stack:**

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed;
>   nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:
>   Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 16]

Comment: Please provide the exception that is thrown.

Comment: Could you include the stack trace and your implementation? It's hard to tell what's going wrong without looking at the trace.

Comment: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 16]

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956348/how-to-convert-object-to-json-of-an-integer-field-having-leading-zeros-using-jac) the JSON spec forbids leading zeroes in JSON.

Comment: @Compass has given you the answer

Answer (score 1):

> However, expMonth is not binding properly and throws an exception.

As per the exception stack, you have leading zeros and hence Jackson is thrwing the exception. You can either try something like,

```
{
    "name": "XXXX",
    "expMonth": 7,    <--- Removing the leading zero(s).
    "expYear": 21
}
```

Another way is to change it to String instead,

```
{
    "name": "XXXX",
    "expMonth": "07",
    "expYear": 21
}
```

**Code:**

```
public Class Card {
     private String name;
     private String expMonth;
     private Integer expYear;
}
```

You can then do something like,

```
Integer.parseInt(expMonth);
```

Comment: I know that String is an easy option. However, this payload has to send to someother api. I just want to avoid the conversion. I'm using ObjectMapper here.

Comment: is there any other way that i can fix the binding

Comment: @SumanthVarada A leading 0 indicates an octal number. Hence, leading zeros are not allowed for numeric values in JSON. See [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)